# How to use a Health Indicator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I have the normal `/actuator/health` and another `/actuator/myHealth`

I simply wanted to check if Rabbit/DB/Disk Size stats in this new `myHealth` endpoint.

```
@Endpoint(id = "myHealth")
@Component
public class CustomHealth {

  @Autowired
private RabbitHealthIndicator rabbitHealthIndicator;    
@Autowired
private DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicator;    
@Autowired
private DiskSpaceHealthIndicator diskSpaceHealthIndicator;      

 @ReadOperation
 public Map<String, Object> health() {
    Health diskSpaceDetails = diskSpaceHealthIndicator.getHealth(true);
    Health dbDetails = dataSourceHealthIndicator.getHealth(true);
    Health rabbitDetails = rabbitHealthIndicator.getHealth(true);

    return ....... // return the data
}
```

}

But I cannot Autowire the indicators.

> Field rabbitHealthIndicator in com.health.CustomHealth required a bean
>   of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator'
>   that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

How can I use and check the health of this indicators in a custom endpoint?

**PS: These stats already appear in the `/actuator/health` endpoint without any problems. The only issue is on `/actuator/myHealth`**

Comment: did you solve the issue?